# Speech Recognition in Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I have created an Interactive voice response system in AsteriskNow3.0. I have obtained Text to Speech with Flite.

How a speech enabled Interactive voice response system can be created using open source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use google services for SR or use SPHiNX.

Note, sphinx is very not trivial setup
  http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Sphinx

Google is

http://zaf.github.io/asterisk-speech-recog/

Comment: I am trying with google services. 
But it shows the following error:-

speech-recog.agi,en-US: Failed to execute '/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/speech-recog.agi': Permission denied

Comment: you need allow asterisk user execute that script. consult your operating system administration manual for instruction(in most system chmod a+x /var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/speech-recog.agi    will work ok)

Comment: I have solved that problem by changing permissions with WinSCP.
Thank you anyways.